How to run a executable from libs dir through ProcessBuilder using java in an Android app
I want to run a Native Executable through Java in Android app
jnilibs path: src/main/jnilib,

Executable name : libnode.so

Note:i have tried name 'node' but result is same

build.gradle file code

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.code.nativetester'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.code.nativetester"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
            }
        }
        ndk{
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // Specify the location of the jniLibs folder
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.1'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.lifecycle.runtime.ktx
    implementation libs.activity.compose
    implementation platform(libs.compose.bom)
    implementation libs.ui
    implementation libs.ui.graphics
    implementation libs.ui.tooling.preview
    implementation libs.material3
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
    androidTestImplementation platform(libs.compose.bom)
    androidTestImplementation libs.ui.test.junit4
    debugImplementation libs.ui.tooling
    debugImplementation libs.ui.test.manifest
}

Run Function in Mainactivity.java
private void runBuilder2(){
        System.out.println("builder2 trying ---->");
        try {

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir+"/node", "-h");
            Process process = builder.start();
            // print its log
            // Capture the process output (stdout)
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            // Read and print the output line by line
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // Wait for the process to finish
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nExited with code: " + exitCode);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Run : IOException error:"+e);
        }

    }

Above function Output
Run : IOException error:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/app/~~Wonxuy8etqj7fN6HSwqrSA==/com.code.nativetester-6QtPkpExKhbZOsI163eTpA==/lib/arm64/node": error=2, No such file or directory
i want  explanation of my problem and a tested solution
Thank you

Seems obvious to me that file /data/app/~~Wonxuy8etqj7fN6HSwqrSA==/com.code.nativetester-6QtPkpExKhbZOsI163eTpA==/lib/arm64/node does not exist. Are you certain that the path is correct?

i tried everything but it always said file not found
i tried: getDir() , nativedir , and just name too , but always said file not found

Have you configured your APK to extract native libraries (legacy mode)? Normally libs nowadays are no longer extracted but directly loaded from within the APK (where they are stored uncompressed and aligned to 4K boundaries) by a special loading method.

how can i configure to extract
